# Vbscript start vbs with arguments and define multiple arguments

Tags: vbscript, arguments

I need to start a `vbs script` by an argument and related to the passed argument see a pop up.

**Example :**

```
Dim Arg, var1, var2
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

'Parameter1, begin with index0
var1 = Arg(0)



if (instr(WScript.Arguments.Name,"Printer")> 0 then
wscript.echo "Printer type..."
end if

if (instr(WScript.Arguments.Name,"help")> 0 then
wscript.echo "help..."
end if
```

Thanks in advance

```
'Clear the objects at the end of your script.
set Arg = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

call you script like so

```
myscript.vbs /help
```

and access args like so

```
'setup the named argument collection 
set argNamedCollection = WScript.Arguments.Named


'get the arguments passed in
argHelp = argNamedCollection.Item("help")
argPrinter = argNamedCollection.Item("printer")

      'or check directly
'check for help arguments   
if argNamedCollection.Exists("help") then
    'do somthing
end if
```